# Faceting search with dynamic boundaries in hybris 5

Tags: java, faceted-search, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to realize faceting search with dynamic boundaries in hybris.

I have not ideas how to make it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Facet boundaries, and I am going to assume you mean "Ranges" in the terminology used in hybris, are pushed into SOLR if using a default hybris Accelerator site.

To make these "dynamic" you will probably need to implement https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1581 and integrate this via the solrfacetsearch extension.